# bash | counting files without "find"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a bash program to count number of files, directories, links in a directory, i'm trying to compare the first character of the rights given to the file, that's mean that i'll apply the command ls -l for each file and then compare the first letter, for for a file i get  -rwxrwxr-x which means it's a file cause it starts with - and drwxrwxr-x means it's a directory cause it starts with a "d", i wrote this code but it doesn't work correctly and i don't know why, thank you

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=$'\n'

for f in `ls -l $1 | tail -n +2 `
do
fic=0
rep=0
lie=0
autre=0

t=${f:0:1}

case "$t" in
    ("-")
        fic=$((fic+1))
        ;;
    ("d")
        rep=$((rep+1))
        ;;
    ("l")
        lie=$((lie+1))
        ;;
    (*)
        autre=$((autre+1))
        ;;

esac

total=$((total+1))
done

command=$(pwd)
echo "Statistique de "$command
echo "Fichier(s) :" $fic
echo "Repertoire(s) :" $rep
echo "Lien(s) symbolique(s) :" $lie
echo "Autre :" $autre
echo "Total :" $total
```

Comment: See: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/74329)

Comment: You better state a good reason why you don't want to use find, which is tailor-made for this?

Comment: You should consider moving the initializations out of the loop.

Comment: Thank you william, it's ok right now,

Comment: Inian, simply beacuse that's what was asked from me, it's a homework

Answer (score 0):

Along with [William Pursell's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829488/bash-counting-files-without-find#comment68877212_40829488) to move the variable initializations outside of the loop, you should use the `test` command to see if a given file is a symlink, directory, plain file, or other.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fic=0
rep=0
lie=0
autre=0

for f in $1/*
do

  if [ -h "$f" ]
  then
    lie=$((++lie))
  elif [ -d "$f" ]
  then
    rep=$((++rep))
  elif [ -f "$f" ]
  then
    fic=$((++fic))
  else
    autre=$((++autre))
  fi

  total=$((++total))
done

command=$(pwd)
echo "Statistique de "$command
echo "Fichier(s) :" $fic
echo "Repertoire(s) :" $rep
echo "Lien(s) symbolique(s) :" $lie
echo "Autre :" $autre
echo "Total :" $total
```

Answer (score 0):

If your bash is equipped with gnu ls , there is also a different way without the need of all those if. Bellow works ok in my bash with ls GNU version 8.25

```
echo "Statistique de "$PWD
echo "Fichier(s) :" $(ls -l |egrep '^-' |wc -l)
echo "Repertoire(s) :" $(ls -l |egrep '^d' |wc -l)
echo "Lien(s) symbolique(s) :" $(ls -l |egrep '^l' |wc -l)
echo "Autre :" $(ls -l |grep -v -e '^l' -e '^d' -e '^-' |wc -l)
echo "Total :" $(ls -l |wc -l)
```